# On uniqueness of a dimension of a manifold.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I get a difficulty in proving:
A set can not be both an r-dimensional segment and a k- dimensional segment.(hint: use implicit function theorem)

Comment: What is the difficulty you get? Do you know the implicit function theorem? Do you know the definition of a $k$-dimensional segment?

Comment: Yes, I know. Assuming a set S is both r and k dimensional. then there exist one to one C^1 functions f and g  on open sets U and V respectively with rank f'=r and rank g'=k. My difficulty is how this assumption contradicts implicit function theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be a connected manifold and suppose $U,V\subset M$ are open in $M$, and $U\cap V\neq\varnothing$. Consider the coordinate charts $\phi_1:U\to\mathbb{R}^r$ and $\phi_2:V\to\mathbb{R}^k$. Then $(U\cap V,\phi_1)$ and $(U\cap V,\phi_2)$ are both charts. The composition $\phi_1\phi_2^{-1}:\phi_2(U\cap V)\to\phi_1(U\cap V)$ is a diffeomorphism. $\phi_2(U\cap V)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $\phi_1(U\cap V)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^r$. But $\phi_1\phi_2^{-1}$ can only be a diffeomorphism if $r=k$.

Comment: Thank you! But I am new for chart's and difeomorphism. What I want to use  is the definition of r- dimensional segment and implicit function theorem. The problem is taken from "Muldowney, advanced calculus lecture notes 217-317 section 4.5.1"